# Angular 5 Input value update with currency pipe

Tags: angular, directive

I am using currency pipe for convert input value in Angular 5 but its working after unfocus input box.. I am looking for solution like while enter the value its mask like the below [a link](http://embed.plnkr.co/zjJw8gfvaVFIUN9OIvea/)..

I tried many solutions not get work

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask

Comment: use ng2-currency-mask to convert currency on the fly

Answer (score 1):

To update value in input field on the fly you need to use [ng2-currency-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask) library

**Step 1 -** Install package -  `npm install ng2-currency-mask --save`

**Step 2 -** - Import module in AppModule

```
import { CurrencyMaskModule } from "ng2-currency-mask";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        CurrencyMaskModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 3 -** Apply mask on the input field

```
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

Comment: its working but not allowing more than 10,000 any config is there ?

Comment: Yes you need to configure options go to official documentation there explain in detail